# How to access a tabbar object from its views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar on my main window.  Each individual tab item has its own view. How can enable/disable other tab items from another tab item view?

Comment: What do you mean by enable/disable? Do you use a UITabbarcontroller?

Comment: What I mean is to be able to access another tab item and change its setEnabled to FALSE or TRUE.

Comment: Lets say in the view controller associated with tab 0, I want to disable tab 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess u want to change the settings of the objects u have in other tab. U can achieve this using NSUserDefaults or by passing the value to the view where u want to change the settings.
Consider an example where u want to disable a button in another tab from the current tab view. Just set an NSUserDefaults to a certain value and assign it to a key. U can access the value u set for the particular key in another view again by using NSUserDefaults. U can check whether the value is what u set in viewWillAppear method of the other tab view. And based on that condition u can enable or disable the controls. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think this is a good technique and I may use it later.  However, unless I don't think it is quite applicable to my current situation.

Comment: continued - I have a tab bar let's say with tab items: 0, 1, 2, 3.  In tab 0, I want to disable tab 1 or enable tab 1.  The way you explained, it seems that I have to have tab1 view loaded and then I can change thins.  But if tab 1 is disabled and its can not get loaded how do I enable it?

Comment: Thanks.  This is the solution that I need but the following statement in the view controller associated with tab 0: UITabBar * tabBarItem = [[self.tabBarController items] objectAtIndex:1]; throws the "unrecogniized selector sent to instance ...".  Any thought?

Answer (score 5):

You can access the *tabBarItems* only by using the view controllers in the *tabBarController*. Use the following code to disable *tabBarItem 1*, from any view controller.

```
UIViewController *vc_1;
vc_1 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[vc_1 tabBarItem].enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your viewcontroller you can do:

self.tabBarController

this gives you the tabbar controller in which the viewcontroller resides. From there you can access other viewcontrollers, the tabs etc etc.